# Always display ALV Grid as ALV List?

Tags: alv

I have a following issue.

I would like to display an ALV Grid always as ALV list for my user. So instead of always doing that...

[image: Display as list]

...I would like to set a variable or something in, for example, `SU01` that would always show me the output as ALV list.

[image: ALV list display]

Is there a trick that would allow me to do so? The ALV grid is presented from SAP standard transaction so I do not have control over the ABAP code under the hood.

EDIT:

I have a possibility to change layout.

[image: Change layout possibility]

However the only options I have are *SAP List Viewer* and *Microsoft Excel*.

[image: View options]

When I choose *SAP List Viewer* the view I get is the ALV Grid.

[image: ALV grid]

Comment: Do you have the option to select a layout variant from the selection screen?

Comment: @vwegert I have edited the question and put more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible system-wide. It can be done only for separate transactions.

e.g. FB
[image: FB]

or [ME](https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/1801484).

Answer (score 1):

Try setting a own data Set/Parameter ID  **FIT_ALVC** to **X** in your user profile Parameters tab

To get to that screen go menu "System>User profile>Own Data 
...then click on the Parameters tab

Comment: Hi, it looks like that it works only for a specific application (FI in this case?). On the Banking System I am working on, this parameter is not available at all. On an ERP system it is available, however seems to be ignored for example in Transaction `/SAPPO/PPO2`.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. I changed the company, and my setting is as its on the picture with date 8.8.2012, but I want to change it to the screen I was used to have the second ALV Grid. Can you please help with this?
I don not even have the possibility to change the layout as is on the picture above. But my colleagues in here have the ALV Grid view since the beginning. So there should be an option. I am despaired already so thank you for all your pieces of advice.

Found it!

On `FBL1/3/5N` screen, go to Settings-->Switch List. That should get you ALV
list.

Hope it can help somebody.