# Change report display from ALV Grid to ALV List Viewer

Tags: abap, alv

I've been asked to change an ALV Grid report to ALV List Viewer. What I have found so far is that the only thing I need is to replace the `REUSE_ALV_GRID_DISPLAY` function for `REUSE_ALV_LIST_DISPLAY` (please correct me if I am wrong).

However, the report I need to change is using the `cl_gui_alv_grid` class which does not use the functions above.

What can I do to change the report using `cl_gui_alv_grid`? Or there is no way and I have to rewrite the code and use `REUSE_ALV_LIST_DISPLAY`?

Comment: Hmmm. What is the detsailed requirement? Usually one would not return to those function modules, if already ported/coded in OOP. But You can easily switch the output option from the sap-menu-bar. And, regarding changes to the current code, You can replace the call to cl_gui_alv_grid->set_table_for_first_display with the proper methods of cl_gui_alv_grid factory.
But this will allow display only, and some minor selection and functions, if a PF_STATUS is also set properly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a setting that would let me display ALV Grid always as ALV List?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17537900/is-there-a-setting-that-would-let-me-display-alv-grid-always-as-alv-list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is impossible with `cl_gui_alv_grid`. You should use `cl_salv_table` with `list-display` parameter to accomplish this:

```
    cl_salv_table=>factory(
      EXPORTING 
        list_display = abap_true
      IMPORTING
        r_salv_table = o_alv
      CHANGING
        t_table      = lt_table ).
```

Answer (score 0):

You can invoke the 'list output'-function in the toolbar of `cl_gui_alv_grid` by calling `set_function_code` as shown below.

```
DATA ucomm_list_output TYPE syucomm VALUE '&RNT_PREV'.
DATA alv TYPE REF TO cl_gui_alv_grid.

...

alv->set_function_code(
  CHANGING
    c_ucomm = ucomm_list_output
).
```